# Apply Shipping Method With Highest Price Rule in Magento

Tags: magento

I have Installed Amasty extension for shipping which comes with Shipping rules, shipping table rates, shipping restriction

1. Now I have created shipping rules for different categories. I have free shipping and next day shipping options
2. Example: I have created a shipping rule for Mens category and another rule for Womens category. Lets say products in mens category has shipping rate as $5 for next day shipping and in womens as $3.
3. Now if I add the products from both the categories and proceeded to checkout I should show the shipping rate as $5 (i.e) Category with highest shipping rate. But what I am seeing now is only free shipping options at checkout

Please friends help me in achieving this

Thank you